# What's the difference of versions of Sennheiser Headphones HD-25?

Tags: headphones, sennheiser, field-recording, gear, equipment

What's the difference of versions of Sennheiser Headphones HD-25?

HD-25 BE (Basic Edition)
HD-25 Sky
HD-25-1
HD-25-1 II
HD-25 SP
HD-25 SP II
HD-25 C II
HD-25-13
HD-25-13 II

I allready ask to sennheiser team, i'm waiting for their answers. Soon i receive i'll post here.
Meantime I'm hoping you can tell me by your experience or your personal knowledge..

(My interest is for field-recording and studio needs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Says it in this [PDF](http://www.sennheiser.com/sennheiser/products.nsf/resources/EFB3A02B6D2C39E0C1257482003EE614/%24File/HD_25-GB.pdf) on Sennheiser's website:

HD25

- impedance:

  - 70 Ω (HD 25-1 II)
  - 70 Ω (HD 25-C II)
  - 600 Ω (HD 25-13 II)
  - 70 Ω (HD 25-II)
- cable length

  - HD 25-1 II: 1,5 m
  - HD 25-C II: 3 m (1 m)
  - HD 25-13 II: 3 m
  - HD 25-II: 2 m
- SPL: 120 dB
- Frequency response: 16 – 22,000 Hz (- 3 dB)

HD25 SP

- impedance: 60 Ω
- SPL: 100 dB ± 2 dB
- Frequency response: 30 – 16,000 Hz (- 3 dB)

Comment: thanks @georgi.m ,but the diference in all this versions is just impedance and one have extra diferences? thanks for your atencion but, there isnt any more diference like bigger earpads.. 
HD-25-1, HD 25-C II and HD 25-II have the same impedance, they are diferent versions only becouse their cable? Isn't weird?

Comment: hey :) they're basically all hd25-s. if they had any other differences except for cable, setup, colour (!), it would have been in the spec.. i think the most important is: hd25sp is not hd25.

Comment: Just re-asking the question as the PDF link is no longer working. Could someone explain what the difference in impedence causes to the sound quality? I recently bought the basic 25-1 and am I correct in thinking the only real difference with the full version is cable length and quality?

Comment: Impedance should match the impedance of whatever you are driving it with.

Comment: 600 Ohms used to be the standard impedance. Now a lot less is the standard. This is because to be load enough the 600 Ohms need a high voltage from the headphone amp. Today many headphone amps in equipment run on five volts and that is not enough to get 600 Ohm headphones loud. Of course, if you can drive them, some say the 600 Ohm ones are better. YMMV.